# Extending operator from $\ell^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$: when is random series well defined?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, compact-operators

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$ be a centered random variable, distributed according to a Borel probability measure $\mu$.

Suppose additionally that $x$ has bounded covariance operator, in the sense that for any $y$ with finitely many nonzero entries (i.e., a functional in the topological dual to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$), we have
$$
\int \Big(\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j y_j\Big)^2 \, \mu(dx) \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty y_j^2. 
$$

Consider a compact operator $T$ on the sequence space $\ell^2$, so that for $z \in \ell^2$,
$$
Tz = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sigma_i \langle z, u_i \rangle_{\ell^2} v_i. 
$$
where above $\{u_i\}, \{v_i\}$ are two orthonormal sequences in $\ell^2$, and $\sigma_i$ are nonnegative real scalars which tend to $0$ as $i \to \infty$.

I want to understand when it is possible to extend $T$ so that we can have the random variable $Tx$, which we define by
$$
Tx:= \sum_i \sigma_i \langle x, u_i \rangle v_i. 
$$
Is this random variable well defined as a random element of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$? (Note, above I am writing $\langle x, u_i \rangle = \sum_j x_j u_{ij}$.)

Comment: For instance, in the case that $x$ is a vector of independent standard Gaussians, there is a set of full measure on which the formal sum $\langle x, u_i \rangle := \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j u_{ij}$ converges for all $i$; hence $Tx$ can be regarded as an element of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.